# Why is my GPS reception poor?

Tags: gps, motorola-droid-x

I get very poor GPS reception on my Droid X.  When I turn GPS on, the little icon in the overhead bar has a flashing center, which means it hasn't found a satellite.  It takes forever to lock on, if at all.

I've found it's better if I move around -- if I walk a 100 yards or so, it will often lock on, but not always.

This seems to have changes recently.  It was great, then something changed.  I just hard-reset the phone, so it has fresh settings (and I was having the problem previously, so it's nothing I did then reset).

Is something wrong with the phone?

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of potential variables here, but a hardware failure is certainly one possibility.

After over a year of use, my Nexus One's GPS became terribly slow to lock until I had moved a bit (like you said, maybe 100 yards) or was outside in a relatively clear area. I assumed this was because the GPS chip had, over time, started to develop problems and was likely throwing errors - oftentimes it would have my location totally wrong, and it wouldn't come on/off correctly.

Download a GPS test app, like GPS Status and Toolbox ([link here](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2&feature=search_result)), and see how long it takes to pick up satellites.

Also, are you using a custom ROM? I've found some ROMs "tweak" Android's default GPS settings, and this could potentially cause issues.

Really, there a ton of possibilities here, so it's hard to say. But aging hardware sounds the most likely to me, unless you've recently started using a different custom ROM or kernel, or recently received an update from Motorola.